# TypeError: (0 , firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.getApps) is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement firebase auth in my Nextjs project but I have this error :
[image]

This is my `firebase/config.js` file :

```
import { getApps, initializeApp  } from "firebase/app";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

let firebase_app = getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];

export default firebase_app;
```

For example, this is my `firebase/auth/signIn.js`

```
import firebase_app from "../config";
import { signInWithEmailAndPasword, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);

export default async function signIn(email, password) {
    let result = null,
    error = null;
    try {
        result = await signInWithEmailAndPasword(auth, email, password);
    } catch(e) {
        error = e;
    }

    return { result, error };
    
}
```

And my `app/context/AuthContext.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { onAuthStateChange, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import firebase_app from "@/firebase/config";

const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

export const useAuthContext = () => React.useContext(AuthContext)

export const AuthContextProvider = ({
    children,
}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(true);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
            {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I'm working with Nextjs 13(.4.10) (app directory) and firebase 8(.10.1)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, if someone could help me and get me on the path to the solution it would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: The Firebase API changed significantly between v8 (known as the legacy namespaced SDK) and v9 (known as the modular SDK). You are currently trying to use the modern syntax with the old version of the SDK. Additionally, the current version is v10.2.0 and v8.10.1 is over 2.5yrs old at this point.